# NLTK Library Fail

Tags: python, nltk, python-3.6

I am trying to download the NLTK Library.

I have already run pip install. Since I am using anaconda, the condition was already satisfied

I run

```
import nltk
nltk.download()
```

I get this error:

> showing info
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nltk/nltk_data/gh-pages/index.xml
>   --------------------------------------------------------------------------- UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 nltk.download()
>
> /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py in
>   download(self, info_or_id, download_dir, quiet, force, prefix,
>   halt_on_error, raise_on_error)
>       659             # function should make a new copy of self to use?
>       660             if download_dir is not None: self._download_dir = download_dir
>   --> 661             self._interactive_download()
>       662             return True
>       663
>
> /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py in
>   _interactive_download(self)
>       980         if TKINTER:
>       981             try:
>   --> 982                 DownloaderGUI(self).mainloop()
>       983             except TclError:
>       984                 DownloaderShell(self).run()
>
> /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/nltk/downloader.py in
>   mainloop(self, *args, **kwargs)    1715     1716     def
>   mainloop(self, *args, **kwargs):
>   -> 1717         self.top.mainloop(*args, **kwargs)    1718     1719     #/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
>
> /anaconda/lib/python3.6/tkinter/**init**.py in mainloop(self, n)
>   1275     def mainloop(self, n=0):    1276         """Call the mainloop
>   of Tk."""
>   -> 1277         self.tk.mainloop(n)    1278     def quit(self):    1279         """Quit the Tcl interpreter. All widgets will be
>   destroyed."""
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position
>   0: invalid start byte

I will appreciate help in debugging this

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
sudo pip install -U nltk
```

Then you just test installation

```
python
Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 13 2017, 12:02:49) 
[GCC 7.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import nltk
>>>
```